# Regular expression in java always return true

Tags: java, android, regex

Can you please help me with regex for the following string in android:

```
1.0.2 Build S6B5
```

How it should be:

```
{number}.{number}.{number}{space}Build{space}{S or D orT}{anything up 3 to 4 chars}
```

With help of some king people from here I`ve tried the flowing code:

```
if (name.matches("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\s+Build\\s[SDT].{3,4}"));
```

but it always return True even for:

```
1.0.1 4C0

1.0.1 B 4BD

1.0.4.52A
```

etc.

Comment: [Your solution should not match those strings](https://regex101.com/r/eEnkhL/2). Please post the whole relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [the following code](http://ideone.com/SSRZrf):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String name1 = "1.0.1 4C0";
    String name2 = "1.0.1 B 4BD";
    String name3 = "1.0.4.52A";
    String name4 = "1.0.2 Build S6B5";

    check(name1);
    check(name2);
    check(name3);
    check(name4);
}

private static void check(String name) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\s+Build\\s+([SDT]\\w{3,4})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(name);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("num1: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("num2: " + m.group(2));
        System.out.println("num3: " + m.group(3));
        System.out.println("build: " + m.group(4));
    } else {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
}
```

Use [Matcher.find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) method to match parts of the test string and then `Matcher.group()` method to access the parts captured by the round brackets.

Resulting output:

```
not found
not found
not found
num1: 1
num2: 0
num3: 2
build: S6B5
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one instead : 
(\d{1}).(\d{1}).(\d{1})\s(Build)\s([SDT])([\w\d]{3,4})

or

(\d)*.(\d)*.(\d)*\s(Build)\s([SDT])([\w\d]{3,4}) if you can have multiple numbers.

In your, the problem is the end of the regex : ".{3,4}". It means that you accept ANY character 3 to 4 times.

Comment: I disagree that this is the problem. It should already mismatch on the missing "Build".

Comment: "Build" is not missing from his regex ? This is his regex : `if (name.matches("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\s+Build\\s[SDT].{3,4}"));`

Comment: The is no "Build" in the test data.